Multiple asynchronous opening of requests FDQuery
Please help me with a problem like Firedac (DELPHI 11). I have a hospital application that opens up a lot of FDQUERY and links the cxGrid to the user interface. How to organize multiple asynchronous opening of requests at the same time? Consistently - too long.
For example, there are 20 cxGrid in the user interface. A separate database query is generated for each table. It is not possible to speed up the opening of all tables and show them to the user. Opening 20 requests sequentially is very long, up to 10 seconds
I open all the tables sequentially, which slows down the application very much
